# Error: "Invalid header found" al hacer send_mail

Tags: python, django

Al enviar el email de contacto me devuelve "Invalid header found".
Utilizo servidor de correo sendgrid, pero supongo que el error nada tiene que ver con el servidor de correo, sino con el código de mi programa.
¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Views.py

```
def contact_form(request):
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = f'Message from {form.cleaned_data["name"]}'
            message = form.cleaned_data["message"]
            sender = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            recipients = ['miemail@gmail.com']
            try:
                send_mail(subject,message,sender,recipients, file_silentry=True)
            except:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
            return HttpResponse('Your email has been sent')
    return render(request, 'users/contact.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: Te devuelve "Invalid header found" porque le has pedido tú que devuelva eso en caso de que haya una excepción. Por tanto no sabemos qué está pasando exactamente en el envío, tan sólo que ha ocurrido una excepción, pero eso no implica que haya una cabecera mal. Para depurar, deberías capturar la excepción y enviar esa en vez del mensaje predefinido que tienes. Para ello tienes que poner `except Exception as e:` y dentro `return HttpResponse(str(e))`

Comment: Así lo he hecho y me devuelve que no reconocer file_silentry. Lo he quitado y funciona bien el envío sin problema. No se para qué es exactamente file_silentry pero sin ello funciona bien.

Comment: Quizas querias poner `fail_silently`, es lo mas parecido que he encontrado.

Comment: Así es, muy amable!